# In Django Rest Framework how can I return errors (warnings) from validation / serialization without failing the validation?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have an import that takes data from a foreign API and updates a Django model. The code to do this passes the existing model instance and the incoming data to the serializer class to get an updated instance to save.

For this update I don't want to fail the validation, or the update, if some of the incoming data is wrong, but I would like to notify the errors (warnings) so they can be logged outside of the serializer.

Is there a DRF way of doing this, or any way of doing this?

To be clear: I still want the serializer to validate and raise for other less complex fields, but not the special fields that will need additional processing.

I'm currently over-riding `to_internal_value` in the serializer so that I can deal with the strangely formed data and record error messages before I let the incoming data through to `super().to_internal_value()`: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

My work-around is to add a `warnings` attribute to the serializer to save the messages in. The `to_internal_value` over-ride can then selectively remove bad fields from the incoming data and record warning messages in the `warnings` list.

Update: I think this is going to work but I'm still wondering if there's a better Django built-in approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question because I have worked out my intended solution was more reasonable than I thought. If I get a better answer I'll select it instead.

To be able to raise on some invalid fields but not others requires the incoming serialization to be intercepted to avoid the standard behaviour, which is why `to_internal_value` must be overridden.

To be able to pass back any warnings without raising an exception requires some persistent attribute somewhere, logically on the Serializer object I suppose, because we can't rely on the processing not raising somewhere down the line once we pass execution back to Django ModelSerializer.

This all seems quite solid in retrospect, so I guess I was just being cautious because I hadn't gone this route before. I'd really appreciate anyone raising any gotchas.

Django already has the `errors` `OrderedDict` that it uses in the validation exception to formalise per-field error messages. The trouble is, this can't be accessed until `is_valid()` is called, so another attribute is needed.

Here is a simplified example implementation.
This will work just like the Django ModelSerializer, except the `warnings` attribute can be referenced after calling `is_valid()` for reporting back what happened:

```
class AnObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serialize normal fields using Django ModelSerializer magic to raise when invalid.
    Intercept incoming crazy foreign fields and record warnings when invalid without raise.
    """
    CRAZY_FIELDS = ('foreign_omicron', 'foreign_delta', 'foreign_crazy')
    warnings = {}  # Some field failures will not invalidate but are reported here

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        """Try to add incoming foreign crazy fields or warn if not."""
        foo = data['foo']
        for field in self.CRAZY_FIELDS:
            value = data.pop(field, None) or {}
            value = value.get('foobar') or ''  # Dig crazy field out of the incoming blob
            value = value.lower()  # Normalize crazy field somewhat

            # Do not raise serializers.ValidationError to allow AnObject load to continue
            # But report errors back to caller for logging in warnings list
            if value:
                try:
                    some_external_validation(value)
                except serializers.ValidationError:
                    self.warnings[field] = f'{foo}: foobar "{value}" has a problem'
                    value = ''
            data[field] = value

        validated_data = super().to_internal_value(data)
        return validated_data

    class Meta:
        model = AnObject
        fields = (
            'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux',
            'foreign_omicron', 'foreign_delta', 'foreign_crazy',
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time import only you may:

You can iterate over each object , validate it using serializer manually. If the data is valid you may update else you keep a log file with the exceptional objects that failed validation.

A serializer wont do what you are asking, you need to catch the error or you need to modify the validation function for the fields to pass, if you dont want it to fail. he standard purpose of serializer that it will raise error on invalid data.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Uzzal.
This is not a one time import.
We already iterate over the objects catching exceptions.
I believe I understand the behaviour of the serializer to raise.
The data I detect should not invalidate the response. That is my question.
The `to_internal_value` override detects unwanted data and removes it so the validation can continue over the rest of the fields and the instance can be saved.
But I then wanted to capture which data was removed in order to allow the validation.
I need the serializer to pass back information even when it validated.

Comment: I see your case. Can’t you do a second time validation while saving checking if the object was okay or not ? Just to filter the unfit objects anyway?

Comment: you mean: 1) validate and catch exceptions 2) record exceptions 3) remove offending data that caused exceptions  as long as it is from the special fields 4) re-validate ? Is that what you're proposing?

Comment: Yes, this is a long process but this worked for me for kind of similar work.

Comment: You could argue that was more "Django-istic" @Uzzal, but I'm not doing the work twice when the whole point of Django magic is supposedly to make things easy and *reduce* boilerplate, not increase *work*. I think this is a clear case for over-riding the default behaviour, but the only thing that doesn't fit the Django model is my additional attribute for recording the warnings. I wish the errors attribute was on the serializer, not just passed in the exception. Then I could just add them there. I wonder if this is a case to update Django?

Comment: I am not sure if Django needs update or if there is any other better way to do this, which I haven't discovered yet. This question needs more attraction.